# Create common ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following in my controller;

```
    public ActionResult CocktailLoungeBarAttendant()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult cocktailLoungebarattendant(string name, string email, string phone)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult merchandisecoordinator()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult merchandisecoordinator(string name, string email, string phone)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This only occurs 4 times but it bugs me that I have the code repeated 4 times.

I then have a BaseController that then grabs the parameters and does stuff with them;

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
```

I'd like to be able to do away with the Post `ActionResult`'s and have a single one in a base controller say.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What are your POST actions doing? Isn't there any difference in the processing between the 2? I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I won't do that at all, even if I don't believe it's possible. It complicates code much without any value. Have base classes is very old-school as for me :)

Comment: there is no difference in what the posts are doing no, hence my "desire" to not repeat code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is this:
In your (base)controller add:

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
    {
        var controllerName = GetControllerName();
        var name = GetViewName(ControllerContext, string.Format("~/Views/{0}/{1}.cshtml",controllerName, actionName));
        if (name != null)
        {
            var result = new ViewResult
                            {
                                ViewName = name
                            };
            result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnknownAction(actionName);
    }

    protected string GetViewName(ControllerContext context, params string[] names)
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
            if (result.View != null)
                return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This will try to check if a view exists for methods not defined. I think you can extend it from here on your own to suit your needs.